# Ignorar error en json desde jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo el siguiente problema, cuando hago una llamada

```
var googleAPI = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/"+item.id;
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET', 
    url: googleAPI, 
    data: { pub : 'value' }, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (item) { 
                    titulo.value = item.volumeInfo.title;
                    autor.value = item.volumeInfo.authors; 
                    reseña.value = item.volumeInfo.description;  
                    categoria.value =  item.volumeInfo.categories;
                    año.value = item.volumeInfo.publishedDate;
                    idioma.value = item.volumeInfo.language;
                    num_paginas.value = item.volumeInfo.pageCount; 
    },
    error: function(libro, status, jqXHR) {
    }  
});
```

cuando están todos no tengo problemas, pero aveces el "item.volumeInfo.authors" no existe en algunos libros y deja se seguir cambiando a los demás. Se detiene. Si el campo existiera pero esta vació, podría hacer algo... pero como NO existe no sé qué hacer, ya que no tengo mucho conocimiento. ¿No se si se entiende? Saludos.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estás **seguro** de que el objeto volumeInfo existe, podés usar esto para saltearte errores de referencia producidos cuando un objeto no tiene cierta propiedad:

```
autor.value = item.volumeInfo.authors || false;
```

Tené en cuenta que esto sólo funciona para referenciar propiedades de objetos que existen. Si el objeto no existe, te va a tirar un error.

Comment: exactamente me pasaba eso el objeto volumeInfo siempre existía pero en ocaciones se quedaba con diferente ruta ejemplo: volumeInfo->[0]->datos_necesarios , muchas gracias por la rápida respuesta :)

Answer (score 0):

Podrías leer los resultados de forma dinámica usando [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

Me he permitido modificar el código, ya que `success` ha sido declarado obsoleto. jQuery recomienda manejar las peticiones Ajax mediante `done, fail, always`. [Ver aquí](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/).

El código muestra dos posibilidades:

1. Mostrar en el HTML la clave del objeto json de la respuesta y el valor de cada clave al lado (esto se construye de forma dinámica, independientemente de lo que haya en el json).
2. Obtener el id de cada elemento y mostrarlo al lado de posibles ids que tendrías en el HTML para cada elemento (funcionaría de forma dinámica, sólo que tendrías cada id de elemento manual en el HTML y aquellos que no vengan en ciertas peticiones quedarían en blanco). Me parece que es más flexible la 1ª posibilidad.

A partir de esos dos ejemplos, creo que todo lo demás es posible.

La URL que uso es una funcional de github, sólo para fines de demostración.

Espero te sirva.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.github.com',
  dataType: 'json',

})
   .done(function( data ) {
 
       //Asignación dinámica
        $.each(data, function(k, v) {
            $("#result").append("<strong>" + k + "</strong>: " +v + "<br>"); 
        });
 
       //Asignación por id
        $.each(data, function(k, v) {
            $("#"+k).append(v + "<br>"); 
        });
    })

    .fail(function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
            alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
            console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
            console.log( "Status: " + status );
            console.dir( xhr );
     })

    .always(function( xhr, status ) {
            alert( "La llamada se ha completado!" );
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div id="result"></div>
<hr />
<p>Ejemplo de asignación por id:</p>

<p id="current_user_url"></p>
</body>
```